# How to compare value from next row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called Order

```
   OrderID        CustomerID        IsPaid  
--------------------------------------------
    1              12                 no      
    2              12                 yes
    3              13                 no      
    4              13                 no
    5              14                 yes      
    6              14                 yes
```

and i have table called Customer

```
   CustomerID      Cust_name    
--------------------------------
    12              John                       
    13              Nick                 
    14              Paul
```

I need to dispaly those customers, who has paid for order, but hasnt paid for previous order, so result should be

```
   CustomerID      Cust_name    
--------------------------------
    12              John
```

Comment: you appear to have multiple customers associated with the same Order ID. Can several people contribute towards the cost of a single order? It's unusual, but possible I guess. Just wanted to check what the data means?

Comment: When you say "previous", do you mean "have any unpaid order in the table", or "the order represented by last row". If it's the latter, you'll need to use window functions.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. OrderID is unique, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT
         cust.CustomerID,
         cust.Cust_name
FROM     customer cust
JOIN     order    paid
  ON     cust.CustomerID = paid.CustomerID
 AND     paid.IsPaid = 'yes'
JOIN     order    unpd
  ON     cust.CustomerID = unpd.CustomerID
 AND     unpd.IsPaid = 'no'
 AND     unpd.OrderID < paid.OrderID
ORDER BY cust.CustomerID,
         cust.Cust_name;
```

Maybe it's a little less expensive doing it as follows:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT
         cust.CustomerID,
         cust.Cust_name
FROM     customer cust
JOIN     order    paid
  ON     cust.CustomerID = paid.CustomerID
 AND     paid.IsPaid = 'yes'
WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM   order unpd
                 WHERE  cust.CustomerID = unpd.CustomerID
                   AND  unpd.IsPaid = 'no'
                   AND  unpd.OrderID < paid.OrderID)
ORDER BY cust.CustomerID,
         cust.Cust_name;
```

Comment: This will compare with *all* earlier orders, not just the immediately previous one.

Comment: @Barmar That's not a problem. If you have a number of paid orders and a number of previous unpaid ones, the order directly after the last unpaid one is paid. Exactly what was requested. I probably don't explain very well but try to write it down...

Comment: I see. Since you use `DISTINCT`, the duplicates will be eliminated. But the join will be more expensive because it's doing a much bigger cross product.

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select c.CustomerID, c.Cust_name
from Customer c inner join
     Order o
     on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
group by c.CustomerID, c.Cust_name   
having min(o.IsPaid) <> max(o.IsPaid);
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you will get output only if exist

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer
       INNER JOIN order
               ON customer.customerid = order.customerid
WHERE  ispaid = 'yes';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question specifically states "hasn't paid for previous order", window functions should be your goto here!

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           LAG(IsPaid) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderId) AS IsPreviousOrderPaid
    FROM #Orders AS o
) ordersWithPrevious
    INNER JOIN #Customer AS c
        ON c.CustomerId = ordersWithPrevious.CustomerID
WHERE ordersWithPrevious.IsPaid = 1
      AND ordersWithPrevious.IsPreviousOrderPaid = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this..

```
SELECT t1.customerid,
       Max(cust_name) AS cust_name
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2 using (customerid)
GROUP  BY t1.customerid
HAVING Group_concat(ispaid) = "no,yes"
```

Online Demo: [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2bd0234d5c5567dd48f2961d23c2cae)

---

Table Structure and Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    OrderID int,
    CustomerID int,
    IsPaid varchar(03)
);

CREATE TABLE Table2(
    CustomerID int,
    Cust_name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES 
(1, 12, 'no'),
(2, 12, 'yes'),
(3, 13, 'no'),
(4, 13, 'no'),
(1, 14, 'yes'),
(2, 14, 'yes');

INSERT INTO Table2
VALUES  
(12, 'John'),
(13, 'Nick'),
(14, 'Paul');
```